# Program to calculate number of blanks, tabs and newlines in a string

Tags: c

```
// Program to calculate number of blanks, tabs and newlines in a string
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int blanks,tabs,newlines;
    char string[30];
    blanks=0;
    tabs=0;
    newlines=0;
    printf("Enter some text less than size 30:\t");
    scanf("%s", &string);
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
       if(string[i]=='')
         blanks++;
       if(string[i]=='\t')
         tabs++;
       if(string[i]=='\n')
         newlines++;
    }
       printf("No of blanks: %d \n No of Tabs: %d \n No of Newlines: %d", blanks,tabs,newlines);
   return 0;
 }
```

This is not getchar()!=EOF version so don't mark it as repeat. Also can't use any library except stdio.h

Comment: try `fgets` to read sting.

Comment: What was your question?  If you are seeking debugging help, you must specifically state how the observed behavior differs from the expected behavior.

Comment: Use `fgets` as others have mentioned. Change `i<30` to `string[i] != 0` or you may count garbage chars at the end. Change `''` to `' '` to count blanks.

Comment: Read  [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You really should be able to find such bugs by yourself. And take the habit of reading the documentation of *every* used function (e.g. of [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and of [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and other [`<stdio.h>` functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io)...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` stops reading when it occurs whitespace,tabs or newline.

> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer
>   must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the
>   input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added
>   automatically. **The input string stops at white space or at the maximum
>   field width, whichever occurs first.**

Thus you are not reading the entire string as you input.

Try using `fgets` as below.

```
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
```

Comment: can u explain string[i]!=0, what's this coding style? moreover below code doesn't count tabs:

Comment: fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
           for(int i=0; string[i]!=0; i++){
               if(string[i]==' ')
                 blanks++;
              if(string[i]=='\t')
                 tabs++;
              if(string[i]=='\n')
                 newlines++;
            }

Comment: @ArvindBakshi `string[i]!=0` to check whether the indexing reached `\0` character. It is to make sure to not access out of bound.

Comment: @ArvindBakshi `C` strings are null terminated by standard.

Comment: what about not calculating tabs?

Comment: @ArvindBakshi It is working perfectly fine other than `if(string[i]=='')` empty char error. It should be `if(string[i]==' ')`

Comment: I have done if(string[i]== '  ') still not counting tabs. using c complier on codechef.com/ide.

Comment: @ArvindBakshi codchef ide is feeding spaces instead of tabs. Try running on different environments.

Comment: Thanks. You are right codechef ide treats tabs as blanks.

Comment: Is there any way to set setbuf(stdout,NULL); for all c code by default in eclipse?

Comment: Can you help me with this - https://github.com/abcool/C_training/blob/Chapter-1/01_1.5.3_1-9.c

Answer (score 1):

> to calculate number of blanks, tabs and newlines in a string

OP's code is almost OK with the string processing, but fails to read user input as needed.

`scanf("%s"` will not save white-spaces.  Use `fgets()`.  [@anoopknr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54001814/program-to-calculate-number-of-blanks-tabs-and-newlines-in-a-string/54002292#comment94840354_54001814)

```
// scanf("%s", &string);
fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin);

// Process the string until a null character is found.
// for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
for(int i=0; string[i]; i++){
   // OP's code should fail to compile as coded.
   // if(string[i]=='')
   if(string[i]==' ')
     blanks++;
   if(string[i]=='\t')
     tabs++;
   if(string[i]=='\n')
     newlines++;
}
```